# How do i get StartPosition location?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

I want in label5.Text to show the StartPosition coordinates X,Y of the form position according to its StartPosition.

Comment: Why would you *ever* write code like that?  Did you ever see a GUI app that displayed its position with text in the window???  Isn't it already obvious to the user where the window is located?  Why do you have to tell him the obvious?  If you *have* to know then use the Load event, at that point the Location property is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick I think

```
 label5.text = this.Location.X + "," + this.Location.Y;
```